# No Main Class Found Error on Other Computers

Tags: java, class, netbeans, executable-jar

I am having a major problem with my java programs. When I run them on my computer (through netbeans), they work perfectly fine. Now the strange thing is that when I build them into a jar file and send it to another computer, they do not work, saying "Error no main classes found" (when I try the jar file on my own computer it works completely normally). Maybe it is something to do with the different java versions and jdks. Or maybe the jar file is messed up. I use the netbeans generated one (after you click clean and build). Please tell me what the problem is and how the fix it.

Comment: Are you running it from within netbeans, or just on the command line.

Comment: I'm presuming that this is a standalone application that you're running it from Netbeans by right clicking the project and selecting run, or run as, or similar. Have you tried running the jar at the command prompt on your machine? Please could you also post the command that you are running on the other machines. Also, checkout this tutorial on running jars, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Check the export process, make it a Runnable Jar File, then choose the main class. If that doesn't work, create a new Jar project and start a fresh by copying all the other files from the old jar to the new one.

Comment: How do I make it a runnable jar file? Is it something in the manifest?

Comment: You make it runnable from when you export the files to a Jar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Netbeans, but, from my experience with `jar`s, your main class should have a method like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Note the string array argument, it's important.
}
```

Your `jar` should also have a properly set `manifest`. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848642/how-to-setup-main-class-in-manifest-file-in-jar-produced-by-netbeans-project) could provide you more insight. I hope this helps.