# How to make a runnable .jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, executable-jar, runnable

for school i have to make a game, together with 2 classmates.
our group had to make something in Java, a language we never used before.
we got ourselfs a little game now, but we can't seem to get it into a working .jar file nor a runnable jar.
We use eclipse, but the .jar file created through export => jar file doesn't work. it doesn't do anything. (manifest file is totally empty)
the runnable jar file is even worse, it says there is no main class selected, but when i try to set 'Main.class' as main class, then it's not in the list. (at advanced options for creating a runnable jar in Eclipse)
i tried through cmd too, but then it couldn't find a manifest attribute...
any help?
my maps:
-Smash'em All
    -.settings
    - bin
         -data (all my images and such)
         -Smash (all the .class files)
         -java.policy.applet
    - src
         -data (some old pictures, not the same as in the other data map)
         -Smash (all the .java files)
    - .classpath
    - .project

any idea how to make a runnable jar?
and if i want to implement it in HTML, do i need a runnable or just a .jar file?
EDIT:
my lay-out doesn't seem saved? :( sorry, is my first post ever herer :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: [How to build an executable jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar)

But you don't really want that, since you want to run you code as a Java applet.

You confuse quite a lot of stuff in your question so my guess is that to get a usable response you will need to provide quite some more details.

Comment: details such as?
i want to be able to make a jar file that i can just doubleclick and that it starts running.
if you need any info, ask me :)

Comment: It's strange that Eclipse doesn't do the job; it certainly works for me. What do you mean by "when i try to set 'Main.class' as main class, then it's not in the list": what list? The one you get when you press the "Browse" button? That suggests you aren't exporting the right class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some that can run with "java -jar" you need to specify the main class in the JAR manifest.

Comment: well, i have no idea how i do so.
what i found on the internet is that i need to set "Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass", but i have no idea how.
just edit in noteblock? and what to?
my main class is "main.class"

Comment: Yes, you can edit the manifest in any text editor. Just make sure you put the edited file back into the jar. In your case the correct line would be `Main-Class: main`

Answer (score 1):

To add to Césars' comment, have you tried:

```
jar cvf YourApplication.jar *.class
```

From "[Java How to Program](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132575663)" :

> That should jar up your classes which creates in the current directory
>   a JAR file named YourApplication.jar containing the applet’s .class
>   files. If the program had other resources, you’d simply add the file
>   names or the folder names in which those resources are stored to the
>   end of the preceding command. The letters cvf are command-line options
>   to the jar command. The c option indicates that the command should
>   create a new JAR file. The v option indicates that the command should
>   produce verbose output so you can see the list of files and
>   directories being included in the JAR file. The f option indicates
>   that the next argument in the command line (YourApplication.jar) is
>   the new JAR file’s name.

As per one of your questions, you asked "if i want to implement it in HTML, do i need a runnable or just a .jar file". No, you can just run the class file, if you want.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <applet code = "YourApplication.class" width = "300" height = "45">
        </applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To run you jar using the java -jar command or double click your jar you need to indicate the main class to run, you do it adding the **Main-Class** in the META-INF/Manifest.MF of your jar, in this link you can see [how to setup the main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848642/how-to-setup-main-class-in-manifest-file-in-jar-produced-by-netbeans-project)

Comment: i tried everything your link suggests, altho i don't have " /nbproject/project.properties"
so i don't know where i should put that line...

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of exe4j tool, which takes your classes in jar and produce exe for you.
try this http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html