# how do i make use of an external jar?

Tags: android, jar, external, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use classes from .jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files)

I am trying to use this external jar from [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

I have added the jar files into my "referenced libraries" but how do I use it?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files

Answer (score 2):

From the Eclipse menu ( seen on top of eclipse ) >>click on **Project** >> **Properties** >>

a dialog box will open. look at the left side and choose : Java Build Path

From there : choose among the TABS : Libraries Tab

Click on the ADD JARs button on the right side.

find the path of the file.

click on the .jar file ( your jar file that you want to be added)
click ok.

done! :)