# json lib errors in my java

Tags: java, json, url

I use Eclipse.I am reading a url and retrieving a json string:

```
String message = "http://XXXXXXXXX";

try {
            website = new URL(message);
            URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));


            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                str1 += inputLine;



        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

try {
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(str1);
                JSONObject results =jsono.getJSONObject("results");
                JSONArray result =results.getJSONArray("result");



            } catch(JSONException ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception thrown: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
```

And I can get it, I can print it out.
Then I wanna parse the json string using JSONArray and JSONObject, but there are errors in the three lines:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

The error is : The `import org.json` cannot be resolved.

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include Json jar in your library .

Download the ZIP file from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip)  and extract it to get the Jar. Add the Jar to your build path. To check the available classes in this Jar use [this URL](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm.).

To Add this Jar to your build path

```
Right click the Project > Build Path > Configure build path> Select Libraries tab > Click Add External Libraries > Select the Jar file Download
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile and run against [the appropriate jar file](http://www.docjar.com/jar_detail/json-org.jar.html).

The above imports merely declare the usage of those classes. You need to provide them during compilation and then during the running of your program e.g.

```
javac -cp json.jar MyTest.java
```

then

```
java -cp json.jar;. MyTest
```

(for example - your compilation and/or packaging may be different)

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files) has more detailed answers.