# Is there a way to use a class's methods in other classes from another projects?

Tags: java

I have been learning java for a while and I'm still a newbie.
I have written a few classes which are quite useful for me and I was wondering if there is any way the I can use their methods in other projects.
Any help will be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

I created the jar file but I can't import it. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files) but for some reason it didn't work. I use eclipse

Comment: you can export the project as JAR file. And add it to the project that needs it.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way would be to put those classes in a jar file, and include that in your other projects.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the build path etc.

Comment: How do you do that exactly? Is there a way to add them to the java.util package?

Comment: @armin Why would you do that, you can just use your own packages.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel I want to know if there is any way that doesn't involve manually adding them ( or the jar file )