# Compile java file with two jars from command line?

Tags: java, jar

Suppose I have two jar files (with classes inside) and a java file:

```
name1.jar
name2.jar
code.java
```

As said at [How to use classes from .jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files), if I wanted to import name1.jar, I could add it to my CLASSPATH, and run

```
javac -cp '.:name1.jar' code.java
```

every time I wanted to import name1.jar. However, how would I compile the java code and import both jar files, not just name1.jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
javac -cp name1.jar:name2.jar code.java
```

note that if you are in Windows path separator should be `;`

Answer (score 0):

The java command can also define the classpath using the -cp flag, which is just a
shortcut for the -classpath flag.

(1)javac -cp "/yourPath/name1.jar;/yourPath/name2.jar;" code.java

(2)javac -classpath "/yourPath/name1.jar;/yourPath/name2.jar;" code.java

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp name1.jar:name2.jar:name3.jar code.java arg1 arg2 arg3
```

this code runs code.java class with jars (name1,name2,name3) -cp used to ignore any runnable jar or other main() and focus on run code.java with arguments arg1 arg2 arg3