# How to import .jar file

Tags: java, jar, import

I've been attempting to import a class contained with in a .jar file. My `my_package.jar` file resides in `/Users/user/Library/Java/Extensions` and my `~/.bashrc` contains the following line `export CLASSPATH = "$CLASSPATH:/Users/user/Library/Java/Extensions`. At the top of my program is a line that reads `import my_package.MyClass;`. Whenever I try to compile the program using `javac MyProgram.java` I get the `package my_package does not exist`. I've done a bit of searching around online and found several possible fixes. One of which involved moving the .jar file to the current directory and invoking javac found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files) as follows.

`javac -cp '.:my_package.jar' MyClass.java`

This yields the same error.

I have also tried changing the `CLASSPATH` to `/Users/David_Johnson/Library/Java/Extensions/` and `/Users/David_Johnson/Library/Java/Extensions/*`. They both yield the same error.

It appears as though I am missing something quite trivial. Any help in catching my mistake would be greatly appreciated.

I'm on Max OSX 10.8.5 using javac 1.7.0_07

Answer (score 0):

CLASSPATH must explicitly list each and every JAR file. Wildcards or directories are not supported.

You can use bash to generate the list though.

```
for jar in /Users/where/ever/they/are/*.jar
do
    CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$jar"
done
export CLASSPATH
```

Comment: I've included your suggestion exactly as you described and I still get the same error. I tried compiling with javac MyClass.java. I made sure to source my ~/.bashrc after implimenting the change you've suggested. I checked my CLASSPATH using echo to verify that the correct .jar file was now included in the CLASSPATH and it indeed is.