# Using Command Prompt to execute a java file

Tags: java, cmd, command, prompt

The problem I'm currently having is that I am trying to execute a java file using command prompt, I understand the PATH being set to the jdk's file. Though my java file contains libraries and has to import the libraries, how would I ' import the libraries ' when it runs?

Sample command : 
javac ClassName.java 1 1 1

When it executes it errors on the imports so what should I do?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2817176/278405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .jar files are Java "libraries".  What you need is something like:

```
> javac ClassName.java
> java -cp Library1.jar:Library2.jar ClassName.class
```

The first line (javac) compiles the Java code into a class file. The second line runs the compiled class.  The '-cp' option sets the CLASSPATH (makes the code in the jar files available at runtime).  Note: the exact syntax will depend on if you are using Mac OSX/Linux or Windows. Windows uses the ';' character to separate the jar file names.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here:

1. Are you compiling or executing?  javac is the compiler.  java is the runtime virtual machine.
2. ClassName.java is source.  ClassName.class is the compiled bytecode run by java.
3. As a general rule, your environment should contain the variable JAVA_HOME, and that should point at the directory where the JDK resides on your computer.

Comment: 1. Executing
2. I'm just executing the source.
3. And the imports are external .jar files, not java libraries.

Comment: You cannot execute the source. You can compile the source.