# Included Jsoup library will compile but not run

Tags: java, jsoup, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to explore webscraping in Java and am just starting with a very basic Jsoup program to get started.  I am pretty sure there is some sort of path issue with what I am doing.  I have tried different variations, and just to get it working have simplified the process by including the library in the same directory as my source file(to simplify the path while I figure out what is going on).  Here is what I have been doing and the output:

```
javac -cp jsoup-1.7.3.jar URLParse.java
```

The above compiles with no errors(it also compiled fine when I had the jar in its own folder and specified the path), the below happens when I try to run the program:

```
java -cp jsoup-1.7.3.jar URLParse.java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: URLParse/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: URLParse.java
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: URLParse.java. Program will exit.
```

The following is the code in case it help:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class URLParse{

   public static void main(String[] args){


      String URL = "http://www.google.com";

      try{

         Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
         System.out.println("Ok here");
         String title = doc.title();

         System.out.println(title);
      } catch (IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

}
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you're not including the directory with the code of your main class in the classpath variable.

```
java -cp jsoup-1.7.3.jar URLParse.java
```

Should be

```
java -cp .:jsoup-1.7.3.jar URLParse
```

On Mac/Linux and

```
java -cp .;jsoup-1.7.3.jar URLParse
```

On Windows. Note that you don't include .java on the class you're trying to run.

[Information taken right from this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817176/3242766)

Comment: Hi Hallfox, thanks for replying.  I am running Linux and I tried your suggestion, it was dead on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a similar directory structure:

[image]

and you are trying to run your `URLParse` class you would need:

```
java -classpath testPackage/jsoup-1.7.2.jar:. testPackage.URLParse
```

[image]

For more details, please refer **[Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/classpath.html)**

Comment: Hi Sandeep thank you for taking the time to respond.  It is executing now.  Thank you for posting the Java Glossary link, I will take a look at it and hopefully get a better grip on working with the classpath.