# How can I determine the org of a given jar and the names of contained packages?

Tags: java, jar

I want to use some of the java classes contained in a jar, say [introcs.jar](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/code/) for example.  As seen in [Java code to import JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730098/java-code-to-import-jar-file), one needs the values of `org` and `somepackage` to import.  If I only have the jar (without any other info.), how can I determine `org` a `somepackage`?  I prefer not to unpack the jar if possible.

It's trivial if `org` and `somepackage` are known.  I know how to add to the `classpath`.

(Windows 10 x64)

Comment: To know what's in the jar, you have to look inside it. That's all there is to it. `jar tf <filename>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked page shows that the classes are all in the top-level package which has no name. Also, it looks like these classes are meant to be run, not imported. To run them, type:

```
java -jar introcs.jar <ClassName>
```

In general, though, any decent jar file should come with documentation saying which package each jar is in. You basically need to know some things about the class you're going to use; at least, what the class does, and how it should be used. And an essential part of "how it should be used" is which package it's in.

Comment: Thank you.  introcs.jar also contains stdlib.jar, which appears to have classes like StdIn.java and StdOut.java that are meant to be imported.

Comment: @trevelyan In this case I think introcs.jar should be extracted into its own directory (`jar xf introcs.jar`). Then you will find the java and class files and the stdlib.jar, which again doesn't use packages. Just run the java classes using `java -cp .;stdlib.jar ClassFile` (use `;` on Windows, and `:` if you're using Linux). You don't need to use an `import` statement because the classes contained in stdlib.jar are in the top-level unnamed package.