# Commands regarding usage of .class files of a jar file

Tags: java, jsoup, classpath

I have the .jar file of jsoup.I referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files) to clear my doubts.
But the solution given there is not working.Even after giving that command,i am getting the following error.

Here is the error.Can someone help me with this.

```
G:\javap>javac -cp .;jsoup.jar Jsou.java
Jsou.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
 Document doc=Jsoup.connect("www.javatpoint.com").get();
 ^
  symbol:   class Document
  location: class Jsou
Jsou.java:9: error: cannot access Jsoup
 Document doc=Jsoup.connect("www.javatpoint.com").get();
              ^
  bad class file: .\Jsoup.class
    class file contains wrong class: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the cla
sspath.
2 errors
```

Comment: .class files of Document and Jsoup must be present in the jar file.Then Why its giving the error "cannot find symbol" ???

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the `Jsou.java` source code?

Comment: @Jonny Henly,Thanks for the help but i got it . I wasn't importing "import org.jsoup.Jsoup"  ,that's why the problem was coming.Now it's fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use classes from .jar files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files) **Note:** This isn't a negative comment. If this question is marked as a duplicate it has no negative impact on you or the question.

Comment: Explore `jsoup.jar` using any zip extractor (WinZip)  and try to Findout is Document class is available in jar or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found by OP:

> @Jonny Henly,Thanks for the help but i got it . I wasn't importing "import org.jsoup.Jsoup" ,that's why the problem was coming.Now it's fine.