# using classes that are in the java archieve file

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to use a class that I've created that is within a java archieve, this is my directory structure: 
[image]
and the directory where all of this is located is the: `/home/user/learning_java`, 
Now I have already seen this question: [using classes in java archieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files), but for some reason this didn't solve my problem(so this is not a duplicate).

I am only using the text editor **vscode** and hence only compile from the terminal(am on ubuntu).

Please ignore the .class files,
The `constructor.java` file has the source code:

```
    package com.beez.java;

public class constructor {
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private int weight;

   public constructor(String var1, int var2) {
      this.name = var1;
      this.age = var2;
      this.weight();
      this.weight = this.get_weight();
   }

   public void weight() {
      double var1 = 5.13D;
      this.weight = (int)((double)this.age * var1 + 3.0D);
   }

   public int get_weight() {
      return this.weight;
   }

   public String get_name() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public int get_age() {
      return this.age;
   }
}
```

and the `run_test.java` has the source code:

```
import com.beez.java.construc.constructor;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class run_test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        constructor niraj = new constructor("niraj", 12);
        int niraj_weight = niraj.get_weight();
        out.println("weight of niraj: "+niraj_weight);

    }
}
```

and I compile in the terminal from the directory: `/home/user/learning_java` which is where the `run_test.java` resides using:

```
javac -classpath '.:com.beez.java.construc.jar' run_test.java
```

and this is the error I get:

```
run_test.java:1: error: package com.beez.java.construc does not exist
import com.beez.java.construc.constructor;
                             ^
run_test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        constructor niraj = new constructor("niraj", 12);
        ^
  symbol:   class constructor
  location: class run_test
run_test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        constructor niraj = new constructor("niraj", 12);
                                ^
  symbol:   class constructor
  location: class run_test
3 errors
```

What is the error I'm making?

Comment: Read the error message. What is the name of the package that it says it cannot find? Read your `constructor.java` file. What is the name of the package you are declaring? Are those two names the same?

Comment: in the classpath you specify location. so try `'.:com/beez/java/constructor.jar'`

Comment: @JörgWMittag , I changed the import to `import com.beez.java.constructor`, but nothing changed.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher , that tells me now that construc.jar is a bad class file

Comment: @juztcode, so perhaps it is bad indeed. check is there were errors when you built the jar file

Comment: @SharonBenAsher,  no, there were not any errors, all it says is that the ` class file contains wrong class: com.beez.java.constructor
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath`

Comment: @juztcode why do you have jar file and class file? you should have only one, not both

Comment: @SharonBenAsher , I've deleted the .class file, but it doesn't change a thing and, you see, I'm just in the phase of learning core java, so, I'm doing all these experiments to learn the language.

Comment: "I changed the import to `import com.beez.java.constructor`, but nothing changed" – Then you didn't recompile, or you recompiled the wrong thing, or you are running an old version of your code, or something along that lines. Since you are now importing from a different package, *at least* the name of the package in the error message *must* have changed.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, yes actually that did change, it used to say `com.beez.java.construc` doesn't exist and now it's saying `com.beez.java` doesn't exist, the jar file's constructor.java successfully compiled to a .class so, that doesn't have to be recompiled? and repacked into the jar? that's not changed at all and it's 100% correct(I mean the code is so simple), and the `run_test.java`, as you can see is doing just this.

Answer (score 1):

in main class you are importing wrong class. The mian class is importing 'com.beez.java.construc.constructor' while you are declaring the package as 'com.beez.java' as package declartion statement. Either correct your import in run_test class or move your constructor class in 'com.beez.java.construc' package.

Comment: I changed the import to: `import com.beez.java.constructor`, but the error didn't change at all.

Comment: and the `construc` was suppose to be the jar file name, since the .class file was called constructor inside the jar file, wasn't that correct, if not what should the import be?