# How do I use a class from my Jar file in my IntelliJ project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, libraries, javaimports

I have a jar file and I am trying to use classes from that file in other programs, and the only way I know how to do that is by copying and pasting the code, which is less than ideal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use classes from .jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files)

Answer (score 0):

- If you do not use Maven or Gradle - [add this jar as a Global library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html?keymap=secondary_intellij_idea_classic#define-library) to an IDE in File | Project Structure | **Global Libraries** tab by selecting `+` then **Java** option:

[image]

- if you use Maven or Gradle - install this library into the local Maven repository (see [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/2000323)) and configure it via Maven/Gradle build configuration.